Old horror movie about a dying man with powers
I’m trying to recall the name of an old horror movie and it’s eluding me.
Time: I watched it in the mid to late 1980s and it was likely an mid 70s to mid 80s movie. 
Country: Almost sure it was American, but it may have be British as the language was English.
Other: It was in color.
The plot: A wealthy family elder has supernatural powers and about to die. The family comes back to claim their soon to be inheritance but are killed off until only one was left and they inherited the power.
Specific scenes: I seem to recall a scene where one family member is drowned because they can’t surface in a pool. Also, I’m pretty sure the last surviving person was a woman.

Sounds like The Legacy from 1978 with Sam Elliott and Roger Daltrey. IMDb's dramatic synopsis:

Six beautiful people arrive for a weekend in the country. Six guests of the unseen host who lies wasting away upstairs...Five heirs to a mysterious Legacy watch the body of the sixth float to the side of the pool...Four claim the unspeakable power of the Legacy, while a red stain spreads across the ceiling...Three realize that the Legacy has come to claim THEM, while outside dogs dine on what was once a man...And then there are two.

The old person who invited his beneficiaries is dying, and he's also a practitioner of black magic. The last person (a woman) standing inherits his house as well as his Legacy, which is his power. Here's the trailer:




This is exactly it. Thanks!
